# SQL - Probably LAG function, need syntax adjustment

Tags: sql

My data looks like this

```
ID     Thing   Date  
123    0       1/1/2018     
123    0       1/3/2018   
123    0       1/4/2018       
123    1       1/5/2018       
123    1       1/6/2018   
456    0       1/2/2018   
456    0       1/3/2018   
456    0       1/4/2018   
789    0       1/2/2018   
789    0       1/3/2018   
789    1       1/4/2018
```

I am looking to get the first record of a 1 in the 'thing' column, where the previous record was a 0. So my output would look like

```
ID     Thing   Date  
123    0       1/4/2018     
123    1       1/5/2018  
789    0       1/3/2018
789    1       1/4/2018
```

I have looked into the LAG function, but i cannot get the correct syntax

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You should post the code you've tried, sql type and the insert statements so we can reproduce your data.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want *just* the "1", then :

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(thing) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_thing
      from t
     ) t
where prev_thing = 0 and thing = 1
order by id, date;
```

However, you also seem to want the row *before* as well.  The following works when the "1" is not first for the id (as in all your examples) and all the things are either "0" or "1":

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where t.date <= (select min(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.thing = 1)
      ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

The idea is to get all rows up to and including the first "1" and then take the last two rows.

Here is a more general solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(thing) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_thing,
             count(*) filter (where thing = 1) over (partition by id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 following) as thing1_counter
      from t
     ) t
where (prev_thing = 0 and thing = 1 and thing1_counter = 1) or
      (thing = 0 and thing1_counter = 1);
```